# MetaMask on page refresh with Web3.js and pure JS

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I am trying to have the MetaMask wallet to stay connected upon the page refresh. However, I could not find any info on that matter on the world-wide-web. Sad. Also, from what I've managed to find, there was supposedly a MM privacy update in 2019, which cut out the injection method...so, is there a way to do it natively with pure JS?

The code so far:

```
const getWeb3 = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
        
        try {
            await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
            resolve(web3)
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("connect_button").addEventListener("click", async ({ target }) => {
        const web3 = await getWeb3()
        const walletAddress = await web3.eth.requestAccounts()
        const walletShort = walletAddress.toString()
        const walletBalanceInWei = await web3.eth.getBalance(walletAddress[0])
        const walletBalanceInEth = Math.round(Web3.utils.fromWei(walletBalanceInWei) * 100) / 100
        
        target.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden")
        
        document.getElementById("wallet_balance").innerText = walletBalanceInEth
        document.getElementById("wallet_info").removeAttribute("hidden") 
        document.getElementById("address_shrt").innerText = walletShort.slice(0,3) + '...' + walletShort.slice(-3)
       
    })
})
```

I have no idea about react whatsoever, so react guides are kinda gibberish to me. Any useful links or directions I could follow at least? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible by design. You have to re-request the address view permission every time your page refreshes (for privacy reasons).

Answer (score 0):

u will stay connected on page refresh with these codes in react,next,next etc.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [ismetamask, setIsmetamask] = useState(false); // is metamask installed ?
  const [accountaddress, setAccountaddress] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window) {
      //sometimes window is not loaded, so wait for windows loading
      if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        console.log("MetaMask is installed!");
        setIsmetamask(true);

        // check if metamask is already connected
        if (window.ethereum._state.accounts.length > 0) {
          // metamask is already connected
          ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts"});
          setAccountaddress(window.ethereum._state.accounts[0]);
        } else {
          // metamask not connected yet
        }

        // trigger when account change: logout or login
        ethereum.on("accountsChanged", function (accounts) {
        if (window.ethereum._state.accounts.length > 0) {
          setAccountaddress(window.ethereum._state.accounts[0]);
        }else{
          setAccountaddress([]);
        }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("metamask not installed");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("window not loaded yet");
    }
  }, []);

  const signinMetamask = async () => {
    // const accounts =
    await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    // const account = accounts[0];
  };

  return (
    <>
      {ismetamask ? (
        <>
          {accountaddress.length < 1 ? (
            <>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  signinMetamask();
                }}
                className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
              >
                Connect Metamask
              </button>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>user: {accountaddress}</>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>metamask not installed</>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```